# Audio player (Reactjs): how to update parent state with a property of child on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

Would appreciate any help here as I'm a Junior and having difficulty adapting other answers. I'm creating a very basic 2-track audio player Application in React. The audio player has global play/pause controls (currently a html audio element) in one child component and a track-list with 2 tracks in a sibling component.

Each track has a button which on click should play the selected audio in the global audio element. The global audio element has a default audio src which is an initial Application state. I would like this state to update on click to the audio source of the selected track.

I have managed to establish communication channels between the parent Application and each child but I can't seem to update the Application state to the audio src of the selected track. My understanding is that the onTrackChange function in the Application is where this action should take place. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var TRACKLIST = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "song a",
        source: "./audio/one.m4a"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "song b",
        source: "./audio/two.m4a"
    }
]

function Track(props) {
    return (
        <div className="track">
            <div className="meta">
                <div className="name">
                    <h2>{props.name}</h2>
                </div>
                <audio>
                    <source src={props.source} />
                </audio>
            </div>
            <button className="select" onClick={function() {props.onChange();}} >
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

function Controls(props) {
    return (
        <div className="controls">
            <audio controls>
                <source src={props.source} />
            </audio>
        </div>
    )
}

var Application = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            isPlaying: "./audio/one.m4a"
        };
    },

    onTrackChange: function() {
        // Is it here where the action should take place?
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="player">
                <div className="tracklist">
                    {this.props.tracklist.map(function(track){
                        return <Track
                                    key={track.id}
                                    name={track.name}
                                    source={track.source}
                                    onChange={this.onTrackChange} />
                    }.bind(this))}
                </div>
                <Controls source={this.state.isPlaying} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});

// Render the UI
ReactDOM.render(
    <Application tracklist={TRACKLIST} />,
    document.getElementById('Player')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the source into the `onChange` function

```
function Track(props) {
    return (
        <div className="track">
            <div className="meta">
                <div className="name">
                    <h2>{props.name}</h2>
                </div>
                <audio>
                    <source src={props.source} />
                </audio>
            </div>
            <button className="select" onClick={function() {props.onChange(props.source);}} >
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then use it to set the state in the parent

```
var Application = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            isPlaying: "./audio/one.m4a"
        };
    },

    // you may need to `.bind(this)` before calling it (or in the constructor
    onTrackChange: function(source) {
        this.setState({ isPlaying: source })
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="player">
                <div className="tracklist">
                    {this.props.tracklist.map(function(track){
                        return <Track
                                    key={track.id}
                                    name={track.name}
                                    source={track.source}
                                    onChange={this.onTrackChange} />
                    }.bind(this))}
                </div>
                <Controls source={this.state.isPlaying} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

---

#### Another solution

This one is basically the same, but only requires changing one component.  Rather than using `onTrackChange` directly as the `onChange` handler, wrap it to use pass through `track.source`

```
var Application = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            isPlaying: "./audio/one.m4a"
        };
    },

    // you may need to `.bind(this)` before calling it (or in the constructor
    onTrackChange: function(source) {
        this.setState({ isPlaying: source })
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="player">
                <div className="tracklist">
                    {this.props.tracklist.map(function(track){
                        return <Track
                                    key={track.id}
                                    name={track.name}
                                    source={track.source}
                                    onChange={function() { this.onTrackChange(track.source);}.bind(this)} />
                    }.bind(this))}
                </div>
                <Controls source={this.state.isPlaying} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I opted for your first solution and it does indeed update state.